# javascript convert undefined to object, but undefined seems a string

Tags: javascript

there are many questions with nearly the same title with this errors. i read them but seems different.

If I use a **string directly** in the function `historyDatabase`, it **works**.

If i using the **string in an array** function `historyDatabase`, it **works**.

If I take the string from the config file, I can output it and it looks correct (I use the error function for this).

I don't understand why the string from config causes problems here, but the same string in plain text doesn't cause any problems. Any idea?

```js
        let player = "";
        player = Engine.ConfigDB_GetValue("user", "localratings.save.searchplayerinput");
        error("player = ---" + player + "---"); // this output  is correct seeh

        // const playerData = this.historyDatabase["seeh"]; // this works
        // const playerData = this.historyDatabase[["seeh"]]; // this works
        // const playerData = this.historyDatabase[player]; // this produce errors
        // const playerData = this.historyDatabase[[player]]; // this produce errors
        // const playerData = this.historyDatabase[{player}]; // this produce errors
        const playerData = this.historyDatabase[player]; // this produce errors
```

its part of this source https://gitlab.com/sl5net/LocalRatings/-/commit/891696adebcdd9fffbfce0a889808a3742e8992d used in a open-source game.

## The error-screenshot

[image]

Comment: Based on the screenshot, the configuration database is returning `see`, but your tests are searching for `seeh` in `historyDatabase`. These are two different values.

Comment: @MikeHofer i found the solution by accident/coincidence. cant explain it at the moment.         `let player2 = Engine.ConfigDB_GetValue("user", "localratings.save.searchplayerinput");
        let playerObj = {};
        playerObj = player2;
        const playerData = this.historyDatabase[playerObj];`

Comment: That's far more code than is in the original sample! :) But I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

- the hard-coded example string was implicitly converted into an object.
- the example array was implicitly converted to an object.

but the string from the text file was not automatically converted.
I do not know why.

the solution was to pass the string from the config file as an object.

```js
        let playerObj = {};
        playerObj =  Engine.ConfigDB_GetValue("user", "localratings.save.searchplayerinput");
        const playerData = this.historyDatabase[playerObj];
```